# How to use for_each with the function as the overloaded operator()

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator

I have a std::vector of function objects. Each object can take an int, so I can say obj(4) and get an int result. How can I use the algorithm for_each to work on each element of the vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create a functor 'calling' each object:

```
struct Caller {
  int value;
  void operator()( const YourFunctorHere& f ) const {
    f( value );
  }
} caller;
std::for_each( functors.begin(), functors.end(), caller );
```

Comment: it also has to inherit unary_function

Comment: You don't HAVE TO write functor, a simple function works as well.

Comment: You might also get somewhere using 

`bind2nd( mem_fun_ref( YourFHere::memberfunction ), 4 )`...

Comment: @John Smith: it is required for e.g. `transform` and `copy`.  `for_each` doesn't need the `unary_function` members.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of C++?  C++0x Lambdas make this short and sweet.

In C++03, for loop will be simpler than `for_each`.

To use `for_each` in C++03, you need to create a functor that stores all the input arguments in member variables and pass it to for_each.  Each functor in the vector will be passed to this visitor functor as an argument, you then need to call its operator() with the stored arguments.